# Java: How do I change the order of my JLabels in a 2x2 GridLayout?

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem in that I'm trying to get my program to print out one particular JPanel as a 2x2 GridLayout with Icons of playing cards on top, and text indicating which player's card is it on bottom, but no matter what I do, the result is reverse, like so. I have tried changing the order in which I add the elements to no avail.

[image: My current result]

```
  CardTable myCardTable 
     = new CardTable("CS 1B CardTable", NUM_CARDS_PER_HAND, NUM_PLAYERS);
  myCardTable.setSize(800, 600);
  myCardTable.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  myCardTable.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  // show everything to the user
  myCardTable.setVisible(true);
  myCardTable.getGamePanel().setBorder(new TitledBorder("Playing Area"));
  myCardTable.getGamePanel().add(playerCard, JLabel.CENTER);
  myCardTable.getGamePanel().add(computerCard, JLabel.CENTER);
  for(int i = 0; i < NUM_PLAYERS; i++)
  {
      JLabel temp = new JLabel(GUICard.getIcon(generateRandomCard()));
      myCardTable.getGamePanel().add(temp); 
  }
```

Below is the constructor of the class that I made, CardTable, that extends JFrame.

```
  static int MAX_CARDS_PER_HAND = 57;
static int MAX_PLAYERS = 2;  // for now, we only allow 2 person games
private int numCardsPerHand;
private int numPlayers;
private JPanel computerPanel, playerPanel, gamePanel;
public CardTable(String title, int numCardsPerHand, int numPlayers) 
{
    super(title);

    setComputerPanel(new JPanel(new GridLayout(1 , numCardsPerHand)));
    setPlayerPanel(new JPanel(new GridLayout(1 , numCardsPerHand)));
    setGamePanel(new JPanel(new GridLayout(2 , numPlayers)));

    setLayout (new BorderLayout(20, 10));
    add(getComputerPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH );
    add(getGamePanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(getPlayerPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

}
```

Comment: It's hard to say why, since the reason for why is not shown in your code. What is your game panel? What layout manager do you have in it? GridLayout (if that's what you're using), will add components starting from top/left, filling a complete row with all columns until breaking for the next row. Hence, the first first components should be cards, and the next two should be labels. But, only if the game panel IS a GridLayout...

Comment: One thing more that confuse me when I read your code is; you have hardcoded "playerCard" and "computerCard", meaning that you'll always have two players; you and the computer -- but then you add a for-loop of NUM_PLAYERS where you'll (possibly) add many more labels...? You have, and will always have two players, or am I missing something?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> "GridLayout with Icons of playing cards on top, and text indicating which player's card is it on bottom,"

You can put text *and* an icon in the same label and just set the text positions with `setXxxTextPosition()`. Maybe you'd prefer *this*. IMO it looks much cleaner than separating the icon and text so far apart from each other.

[image]

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class PlayerCard {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ImageIcon playerIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/1.png"));
                ImageIcon compIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/14.png"));
                JLabel playerLabel = new JLabel(playerIcon);
                JLabel compLabel = new JLabel(compIcon);
                playerLabel.setText("Player Card");
                compLabel.setText("Computer Card");
                playerLabel.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
                compLabel.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.BOTTOM);
                playerLabel.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
                compLabel.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);

                JPanel playerPanel = new JPanel();
                playerPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Player"));
                playerPanel.add(playerLabel);

                JPanel compPanel = new JPanel();
                compPanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Computer"));
                compPanel.add(compLabel);

                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.add(playerPanel);
                panel.add(compPanel);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you really *must* stick with the `GridLayout`, you need to make sure to add the cards *first*, then add the text labels.

[image]

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class PlayerCard {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ImageIcon playerIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/1.png"));
                ImageIcon compIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/14.png"));
                JLabel playerLabel = new JLabel(playerIcon);
                JLabel compLabel = new JLabel(compIcon);
                JLabel playerText = new JLabel("Player Card");
                JLabel compText = new JLabel("Computer Card");

                playerLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                compLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

                JPanel playerCardPanel = new JPanel();
                playerCardPanel.add(playerLabel);

                JPanel compCardPanel = new JPanel();
                compCardPanel.add(compLabel);

                JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2));
                panel.add(playerCardPanel);
                panel.add(compCardPanel);
                panel.add(playerText);
                panel.add(compText);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems interesting, and I'd definitely go for it if I weren't doing this for homework. That said, I think we all remember how an*l CS professors can be about project specifications, so I'm afraid I can't risk it. I appreciate your efforts though, thank for you that.

Comment: @user2019645 did the professor _specifically_ say to use a 2x2 `GirsLayout` for the center panel?

Comment: No, the entire assignment that was given to us seemed very open in that worryingly ambiguous way, if that makes sense. It doesn't help that the assignment is over 6 pages long. That said, I'm about 80% sure that your answer would get full credit with him, but I can clearly imagine him docking points off of me for not following project specifications.

Comment: If it isn't specified, just go with this. It's looks much cleaner than separating the text and label so far apart. You can just use a 1x2 grid.

Comment: Will there be more than one player card or computer card in the center in any given time?

Comment: Never. There will only be one of each card from each other, and two players

Comment: @user2019645 Well you have two options. I have posted the second. You just need to add the cards first, then add the text label, if your going to use a 2x2. But like I said, I think the 1x2 looks cleaner.